# How to add dynamic content in ExpansionTile on drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a ListViewBuilder in ExpansionTile. The expansion tile in the left side drawer. Im new in flutter, i dont know how to add this ? Please help me to fix this ?

```
 drawer: Drawer(
 child: Container(
    child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
ListTile(......),
ListTile(......),
ListTile(......),
 ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(
    'Game Rules',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
  leading: new IconButton(
    icon: new Icon(
      Icons.wb_iridescent,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _rules.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(_rules[index]['category']);
        })
  ],
),

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ListView.builder` - add - `shrinkWrap: true,`

```
ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,  // Add this
                        itemCount: _rules.length,
                       // itemCount: 10,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Text(_rules[index]['category']);
                         // return Text('$index');
                        })
```